# Reordering NSCollectionView with (Flow Layout)

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

I have a NSCollectionView, which I want to reorder. I´m using a Flow Layout, Delegate and Datasource is set to my ViewController.
I have also registered my drag type but I only get the delegate call for:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView canDragItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
```

But not for the other delegate calls. Here is my ViewController source code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewItem.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *strings;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.
}


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.strings = @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h"];

    NSArray *supportedTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CustomDDType", nil];
    [self.collectionView registerForDraggedTypes:supportedTypes];
}


#pragma mark CollectionView DataSource


- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger) collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.strings.count;
}



- (NSCollectionViewItem * ) collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewItem *item = [collectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:@"CollectionViewItem" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    item.myTitle.stringValue = [self.strings objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    return item;
}

#pragma mark Drag/Drop

- (BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView canDragItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"canDragItems");
    return YES;
}


-(NSDragOperation)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView validateDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo proposedIndex:(NSInteger *)proposedDropIndex dropOperation:(NSCollectionViewDropOperation *)proposedDropOperation {
    NSLog(@"Validate Drop");
    return NSDragOperationMove;
}


-(BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView writeItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard
{
    NSLog(@"Write Items at indexes : %@", indexes);

    NSData *indexData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:indexes];
    [pasteboard declareTypes:@[@"CustomDDType"] owner:self];
    [pasteboard setData:indexData forType:@"CustomDDType"];

    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView acceptDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo index:(NSInteger)index dropOperation:(NSCollectionViewDropOperation)dropOperation {
    NSLog(@"Accept Drop");

    NSPasteboard *pBoard = [draggingInfo draggingPasteboard];
    NSData *indexData = [pBoard dataForType:@"CustomDDType"];
    NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:indexData];
    NSInteger draggedCell = [indexes firstIndex];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Did I miss something? I cannot use the new delegate calls, introduced in 10.11, because my project needs to run before.

Comment: Can you use flow layout before 10.11?

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I think it is not possible. Currently changing the collection view to content array layout.

Comment: I have the same issue and it drives me mad. Did you find any solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

OK!!!  So you are re-Ordering a flow layout!   This can be tricky -   I am not on my Mac so i will give you the 'Overview'

When reordering any Table / Collection  and you have multiple changes,  you need to **batch update** to datasource.  (you may already know that)

Make sure to connect your datasource and delegate to the view.  (i dont see it in code so i suppose you did it in interface builder)

Lastly you may want to check that your collection view is Strong (So strong) -  because it may be losing its reference before it ever displays.    -  If none of this works let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I connected the datasource and delegate to my view controller in interface builder. Maybe I don´t need a flow layout. Is it easier to use a Content Array as layout for reordering? But I only getting the canDragItemsAtIndex delegate call.

Comment: Matt -  Do you have the Delegate protocol set?  ViewController : NSCollectionViewDelegate

Comment: Yes, I did set the delegate protocol.